# Prove the normal subgroup of such $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove: if group $G$ **only** has one subgroup $H$ with order unknown, then this subgroup $H$ must be normal.

Note: the normal subgroup must satisfy $gH=Hg$ for any $g \in G$, should we prove that $gH=H, Hg=H$ and get the answer? I just didn't feel right

Comment: Hint: the conjugation of a subgroup is again a subgroup.

Comment: I'm no expert on group theory but doesn't every group have at least the trivial subgroup? Meaning that if there is only one subgroup then it *is* the trivial subgroup which is normal?

Comment: @Spencer: Presumably the question means "only one nontrivial subgroup", because otherwise there are at least two: $G$ itself and $\{1\}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, ah thanks for clarifying that point. The problem makes more sense now.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Actually, I think the question means "only one subgroup of this order", meaning only one subgroup with $3$ elements, for example. There may be more nontrivial subgroups of other orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: An equivalent definition of a normal subgroup is $gHg^{-1} = H$ for any $g\in G$. Also, the set $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

Let me elaborate a bit on the hint I gave in the comments.

1. For any element $g\in G$ the set $g^{-1}Hg=\{g^{-1}hg\mid h\in H\}$ is also a subgroup of $G$.
2. A subgroup $H\leq G$ is normal if and only if $g^{-1}Hg=H$ for all $g\in G$.

Can you fill in the missing arguments?